# Spring Boot Spring Batch partitioned job not stopping after COMPLETION

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I recently started writing spring batch program using java config way and using spring batch and starter packages. I used partitioned step and task executor to do my work.The problem I am facing is once the job is COMPLETED the batch process won't stop and it is keep running in my eclipse and in the Linux box. I manually find and kill the job. Can you please help with this.
This working fine when I run the job without partitioned step and in a single threaded way.

My Job Config:

```
 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<MediaAsset> metaDataExportReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[sourceSystemCode]}") String sourceSystemCode,@Value("#{jobParameters[assetType]}") String assetType,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[startingMediaAssetId]}") long startingMediaAssetId,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[endingMediaAssetId]}") long endingMediaAssetId,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[threadName]}") String threadName) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Reader is called...."+sourceSystemCode);
        logger.debug("page size---------->"+jobConfig.getPageOrChunkSizeMetaDataExport());
        logger.debug("startingMediaAssetId---------->"+startingMediaAssetId);
        logger.debug("endingMediaAssetId"+endingMediaAssetId);
        logger.debug("threadName"+threadName);
        final Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("startingMediaAssetId",startingMediaAssetId);
        parameters.put("endingMediaAssetId",endingMediaAssetId);
        JdbcPagingItemReader<MediaAsset> jdbcPagingItemReader = getJdbcPagingItemReader(sourceSystemCode, assetType);
        jdbcPagingItemReader.setParameterValues(parameters);
        return jdbcPagingItemReader;
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<MediaAsset> metaDataExportWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters[sourceSystemCode]}") String sourceSystemCode,@Value("#{jobParameters[assetType]}") String assetType,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[startingMediaAssetId]}") long startingMediaAssetId,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[endingMediaAssetId]}") long endingMediaAssetId,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[threadName]}") String threadName) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("Coming here Item Writer,..."+threadName);
        logger.debug("getItemsPerFile---------->"+jobConfig.getPageOrChunkSizeMetaDataExport());
        //for xml file creation
        StaxEventItemWriter<MediaAsset> staxEventItemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
        staxEventItemWriter.setRootTagName(DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_ROOT_TAG);
        staxEventItemWriter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        staxEventItemWriter.setOverwriteOutput(true);
        //for splitting the files into multiple files based on record size
        MultiResourceItemWriter<MediaAsset> multiResourceItemWriter = new MultiResourceItemWriter<>();
        multiResourceItemWriter.setItemCountLimitPerResource(jobConfig.getPageOrChunkSizeMetaDataExport());
        multiResourceItemWriter.setDelegate(staxEventItemWriter);
        multiResourceItemWriter.setResourceSuffixCreator(new ResourceSuffixCreator() {
            @Override
            public String getSuffix(int index) {
                return DL3ConstantUtil.UNDERSCORE+threadName+DL3ConstantUtil.UNDERSCORE+startingMediaAssetId+DL3ConstantUtil.UNDERSCORE+endingMediaAssetId+DL3ConstantUtil.UNDERSCORE+index+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_FILE_NAME_SUFFIX;
            }
        });
        logger.debug("writer sourceSystemCode"+sourceSystemCode);
        switch (assetType) {
        case DL3ConstantUtil.IMAGE_ASSET:
            switch (sourceSystemCode) {
            case DL3ConstantUtil.LIGHTBOX:
                multiResourceItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DPL"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_LIGHT_BOX_FILE_NAME_PREFIX_NAME_IMG));
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.SOLAR:
                multiResourceItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"SOLAR"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_SOLAR_BOX_FILE_NAME_PREFIX_NAME_IMG));
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.MANUAL_UPLOAD:
                multiResourceItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DDDS"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_DDDS_BOX_FILE_NAME_PREFIX_NAME_IMG));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        break;
        case DL3ConstantUtil.DOCUMENT_ASSET:
            switch (sourceSystemCode) {
            case DL3ConstantUtil.SOLAR:
                multiResourceItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"SOLAR"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_SOLAR_BOX_FILE_NAME_PREFIX_NAME_DOC));
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.MANUAL_UPLOAD:
                multiResourceItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DDDS"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+DL3ConstantUtil.EXPORT_ASSET_METADATA_BY_SOURCESYSTEM_CODE_DDDS_BOX_FILE_NAME_PREFIX_NAME_DOC));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("no matching assetType ");
        }
        return multiResourceItemWriter;
    }


    @Bean(name="GenerateXMLFilesMaster")
    public Step generateXMLFilesMaster(ItemReader<MediaAsset> metaDataExportReader,ItemWriter<MediaAsset> metaDataExportWriter) {
        logger.debug("Master Step initialization...");
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("GenerateXMLFilesMaster").
                partitioner(generateXMLFilesSlave(metaDataExportReader,metaDataExportWriter)).
                partitioner("GenerateXMLFilesSlave",metaDataExportPartioner(null,null,null)).
                partitionHandler(metaDataExportPartionHandler(metaDataExportReader,metaDataExportWriter)).
                build();

    }

    @Bean(name="GenerateXMLFilesSlave")
    public Step generateXMLFilesSlave(ItemReader<MediaAsset> metaDataExportReader,ItemWriter<MediaAsset> metaDataExportWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("GenerateXMLFilesSlave")
                .<MediaAsset, MediaAsset> chunk(jobConfig.getPageOrChunkSizeMetaDataExport())
                .reader(metaDataExportReader)
                .writer(metaDataExportWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name="uploadTaskletMetaData")
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet uploadTaskletMetaData(@Value("#{jobParameters[sourceSystemCode]}") String sourceSystemCode,@Value("#{jobParameters[assetType]}") String assetType){
        MetaDataUploadTasklet metaDataUploadTasklet = new MetaDataUploadTasklet();
        logger.debug("sourceSystemCode----->"+sourceSystemCode);
        logger.debug("assetType----->"+assetType);
        metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath());
        switch (assetType) {
        case DL3ConstantUtil.IMAGE_ASSET:
            switch (sourceSystemCode) {
            case DL3ConstantUtil.LIGHTBOX:
                metaDataUploadTasklet.setSourceDirectory(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DPL"+jobConfig.getBackSlash());
                //metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath()+"/IA/DPL");
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.SOLAR:
                metaDataUploadTasklet.setSourceDirectory(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"SOLAR"+jobConfig.getBackSlash());
                //metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath()+"/IA/SOLAR");
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.MANUAL_UPLOAD:
                metaDataUploadTasklet.setSourceDirectory(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"IA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DDDS"+jobConfig.getBackSlash());
                //metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath()+"/IA/DDDS");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        case DL3ConstantUtil.DOCUMENT_ASSET:
            switch (sourceSystemCode) {
            case DL3ConstantUtil.SOLAR:
                metaDataUploadTasklet.setSourceDirectory(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"SOLAR"+jobConfig.getBackSlash());
                //metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath()+"/DA/SOLAR");
                break;
            case DL3ConstantUtil.MANUAL_UPLOAD:
                metaDataUploadTasklet.setSourceDirectory(jobConfig.getTargetFileLocation()+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DA"+jobConfig.getBackSlash()+"DDDS"+jobConfig.getBackSlash());
                //metaDataUploadTasklet.setTargetFolder(jobConfig.getTargetMetaDataRootPath()+"/DA/DDDS");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


        return metaDataUploadTasklet;
    }

    @Bean(name="UploadXMLFiles")
    public Step uploadXMLFiles(){
         return stepBuilderFactory.get("UploadXMLFiles").tasklet(uploadTaskletMetaData(null,null)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner metaDataExportPartioner(@Value("#{jobParameters[sourceSystemCode]}") String sourceSystemCode,@Value("#{jobParameters[assetType]}") String assetType,@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[totalCount]}") String totalCount){
        logger.debug("source system code--->"+sourceSystemCode);
        logger.debug("assetType--->"+assetType);
        MetaDataExportPartioner metaDataExportPartioner = new MetaDataExportPartioner();
        metaDataExportPartioner.setSourceSystemCode(sourceSystemCode);
        metaDataExportPartioner.setAssetType(assetType);
        logger.debug("In the partioner initiliazation------>"+totalCount);
        metaDataExportPartioner.setTotalCount(StringUtils.isEmpty(totalCount)?0:Integer.parseInt(totalCount));
        return metaDataExportPartioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler metaDataExportPartionHandler(ItemReader<MediaAsset> reader,ItemWriter<MediaAsset> writer){
        logger.debug("Initializing partionHandler------>");
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        partitionHandler.setStep(generateXMLFilesSlave(reader,writer));
        partitionHandler.setGridSize(6);
        partitionHandler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        return partitionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean()
    public JobExecutionListener metaDataExportJobExecutionListener(){
        JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener = new MetaDataExportJobListener();
        return jobExecutionListener;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportMetaDataJob(JobExecutionListener metaDataExportJobExecutionListener) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("ExportMetaDataJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(metaDataExportJobExecutionListener)
                .flow(generateXMLFilesMaster(metaDataExportReader(null,null,0L,0L,null),metaDataExportWriter(null,null,0L,0L,null)))
                //.next(uploadXMLFiles())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

My pom file entries:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-version>1.0.4.RELEASE</spring-cloud-version>
        <spring-batch-admin.version>1.3.0.RELEASE</spring-batch-admin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId> <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring-batch-admin.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> 
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> </exclusion> 
            <exclusion> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.1</version> </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVMs shut down automatically when there are zero non-daemon threads running.  In your non-partitioned situation, you have no non-daemon threads running when the job is complete so the JVM shuts down.  However, in your partitioned use case you must have something waiting for work still preventing the application to shut down.  Doing a thread dump would help diagnose the issue however my bet is that the threads being held by the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` are the issue.  If it is, you may want to look at an option that doesn't create a pool of threads (preventing the JVM from shutting down).

Comment: Hi Michael..nice to see your response..I watched your videos and learned spring batch concepts.By the way I did jstack and found that there were few threads waiting for something.I couldn't find why it is waiting for it. To fix this once the job is completed, I shutdown the threadpool task executor in the jobexecution liseter  afetrjob method which solves the issue.Also few other threads were running/waiting because I have added spring-starter-thymeleaf dependency which defaultly includes all the spring-web,tomcat dependencies.So I excluded those from thymeleaf. Is that a right approach?